# Open new window in webBrowser2

Tags: c#, popup, webbrowser-control

For a project I'm opening a webpage in webBrowser1. When I click something on webBrowser1 it's opening new window in pop-up. I want to open all pop-up's in webBrowser2.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what you had tried so far ?

Comment: Handle the [`WebBrowser.NewWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) event.